# Pandas check if there are repeating values between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets like this:

dataset1:

```
Name | Age
John | 22
Bill | 19
Jess | 21
```

dataset2:

```
Name | Age
Tati | 29
Dray | 18
John | 24
```

I would like to compare the two columns 'Name' of the two dataset and get the output: 'John', as this is the repeating name in the two columns.

The code I have until now:

```
import pandas as pd

first_df = pd.read_excel("dataset1.xlsx")
second_df = pd.read_excel("dataset2.xlsx")

first_df['Name'].isin(second_df['Name']).value_counts()
```

The output is:

```
False: 2
True: 1
```

But I would like to see which exactly is the repeating name.

Comment: There are lot of questions like this please search before post a question to avoid the duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be a [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on `Name` followed by a [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(df2.Name), 'Name'].value_counts()

John    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

If the counts aren't necessary, a simpler way would be:

```
set(first_df.Name).intersection(second_df.Name)
# {'John'}
```

Answer (score 1):

yatu gave a perfectly fine answer, but I just want to show you how close you actually were:

```
multiple_occurrences = first_df["Name"].isin(second_df["Name"])
first_df[multiple_occurrences]
```

Result of last line:

```
   Name  Age
0  John   22
```

Or if you only want to have the name:

```
multiple_occurrences = first_df["Name"].isin(second_df["Name"])
list(first_df[multiple_occurrences]["Name"])
```

Result of last line:

```
['John']
```